# RecyclerView inside RecyclerView not smoothly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

There are some topics about RecyclerView inside RecyclerView but I see most of them do not fit my case. My case is I have a RecyclerView (verticle linear layout management) displays a list of CardView, each Cardview contains a inner RecyclerView (horizontal linear layout management). The problem is all about performance when scrolling, it is not smooth at all. I notice if I comment the setAdapter for the Inner Recyclerview, the scrooling become smooth, but I make the CardView not updated the new list. The code is something similar to this:

```
onBindViewHolder...{
    holder.innerRecycler.setAdapter(new InnerAdapter((data));
    // comment that line make the outer recyclerview smoothly but the CardView data not updated thanks to the view recycling.
}
```

I know a scrollable view inside a scrollable view is not a good idea but I dont see any other choices. Anyone face to this kind of layout before?. Thanks.

UPDATE (add more code).

```
// init outer recyclerview
mOuterRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(...);
mOuterRecyclerView.setLayoutManagement(new LinearLayoutManagement(this));
mOuterRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
mOuterRecyclerView.setAdapter(new OuterAdapter(dataList));

// The adapter class for the outer one
onBindViewHolder(...){
    final dataItem = mItems.get(position);
    holder.innerRecycler.setAdapter(new InnerAdapter(dataItem.getList()));
}

// the holder for the outer
class MyHolder extends ViewHolder{
    RecyclerView innerRecycler;
    public MyHolder(View view){
        super(..);
        innerRecycler = findViewById(...);
    }
}
// the adapter for the inner
onBindViewHolder(...){
    final dataItem = mItems.get(pos);
    // async loading
    holder.tvTitle.setText(dataItem.getTitle);
}
```

The layout is pretty simple so I dont post the fully code here. :)

Comment: yep you are right, this is a very bad practice which reduces performance and affects user experience. I suggest that you move the contents of the inner `RecyclerView `somewhere else, possibly a pop-up on click or a new window.
As for your issue, we can't debug it without seeing what *exactly* you do there

Comment: @Droidman. that is what I supposed, but I want to see if anyone could archive this kind of layout with the best performance. :). thanks for your advice anyway

Comment: You need to post more code

Comment: @ligi, added as required

Comment: Can you post the inneradapter?

Comment: @ligi: Do you have any idea?. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no issue in such an approach as long as they scroll along different axes.You could enable [`RecyclerView.startNestedScroll(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#startNestedScroll(int)) and also handle situations like overscroll.This delay would be because you are reinitiating an adpater everytime. You could try something different like maintaining a map of adpaters and calling [RecyclerView.swapAdapter(args...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#swapAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter,%20boolean)) in bindVH.

Another good step could also be using a common pool for recycled views using  [RecyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(args...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#swapAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter,%20boolean)) .
I have created and used a list of 100+ plus items with a nested (different axis) recycler and have not faced issues .

If you would provide more code( where you have written `async loading`) I could help you more.But I suggest you go through the API and the design patterns and that should solve your issue.

Comment: The swapAdapter did the trick. Although the animation is not smooth as expected, I mark this as answer. thanks. :)

Comment: The 'smoothness' would be dependent on how your bind method is .Optimizing that keeping should do the trick.

Comment: That makes sense. the onBind method of the outer adapter is fast (0ms all the time) but the onBind of the inner takes pretty long (1 - 5ms, sometime it takes up to 20ms). I guess that is the problem for the outer scroll, but the inner scroll is very smooth. ?

Comment: Yup thats the reason,you have to shorten that time.The inner scroll is initialised once all the items are available.For the outer scroll,the inner scroll for views which are about to be visible.The views will not be shown till the bind method is complete.

Comment: I think I got it. The outer scroll get laggy cuz it needs to wait for all the inner adapters (visible ones) complete its onBind method (that clearly takes time). The inner scroll is smooth cuz it deals with 1 list only. If thats true, then there is no best way but optimize the inner onBind method (that affects the outer by arithmetically).

Comment: @Paul, how did you do code the solution, I am trying with swap and didnt for me. Droidekas gave a tips but not an example, could you please post any solution with a code example. Thanks

Comment: @Robert: I have just made a new reply, you can check it out to see if it solves your problem. :)

Comment: @Droidekas . can you please put sample code here about.RecyclerView.swapAdapter(args...)  and RecyclerView.swapAdapter(args...)  . it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 7):

@Paul i had the same requirement and the below trick worked.
Put the parent recyclerview inside NestedScrollView and in your onCreate method, 
set.

```
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

This prevents scroll of parent recyclerview and scroll becomes absolutely smooth.

Comment: Life saver mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
This did the trick.

Comment: For me "Put the parent recyclerview inside NestedScrollView" fixed the problem. Thank you.

Comment: If you put recyclerview inside nestedscroll view then the purpose is not served. You recyclerview will never recycle any child.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are some user ask me how to archive, I'm going to post what I do.
The sugession that @Droidekas seems a good point but I dont follow that.

What I did is:

1. Each horizontal recycler view is a item of a vertical recycler view
2. When I need to set the data for the particular vertical item (onBindViewHolder), I use the horizontal recycler adapter setNotifyDataSetChanged instead of setting a completely new adapter or swapping it. This way, I got the vertical recyler run very smoothly.

The vertical recyler adapter structure could be:

```
Vertical Item view holder  -> Vertical Item[Name, List<Horizontal item>,...]
Vertical Item view holder  -> Vertical Item[Name, List<Horizontal item>,...]
```

In OnBindViewHolder

```
holder.setData(VerticalItem)
```

In the Holder, I have a setData method looks like:

```
setData(VerticalItem item){
    mItems = item.getHorizontalItems();
    mHorizontalAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Hope it helps. :D

Comment: I think here the key point is: move your LinearLayoutManager and adapter init code to the viewHolder from the onBindViewHolder.